# How can leading apostrophes in a CSV file be opened and saved by Excel without data loss?

Tags: excel, csv, escaping, data-loss

We're trying to use CSV files from Python in a way that allows users to edit them in Excel, without data loss. However, the use of apostrophes in Excel to escape text plus the implementation of the CSV format seems to prevent this. For clarity, I will use the following terms:

- *quoted* to refer to a CSV cell which has text quoting using double quotes, and *unquoted* to refer to a cell which doesn't
- *apostrophe-escaped* to refer to an Excel cell that has a leading apostrophe as a text marker in the underlying value in Excel, but displayed without that leading apostrophe

Based on experimentation, it seems that:

- A single, unquoted `'` in a CSV cell gets opened in Excel as a cell containing an apostrophe-escaped blank string (underlying value of `'`, displayed as an empty cell)
- A single, quoted `'` in a CSV cell gets opened in Excel as a cell containing an apostrophe-escaped single apostrophe  (underlying value of `''`, displayed as `'`)
- An Excel cell containing an apostrophe-escaped blank string gets saved as an empty CSV cell
- An Excel cell containing an apostrophe-escaped apostrophe gets saved as a single unquoted `'`

This means that even quoting a single apostrophe in a CSV cell results in an unquoted apostrophe when opened and saved by Excel; the next time this file is opened and saved by Excel it will result in a blank cell. Is it possible to avoid this data loss?

PS I know that [CSV is not a fully standardized file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard); however I have not been able to find any documentation that specifically solves the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to replace the single quote (apostrophe) prior to storing the strings in Excel.........this example uses **tilda**

```
Sub ImportFile()
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.csv" For Input As #1
    j = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            TextLine = Replace(TextLine, "'", "^")
            Cells(j, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            Cells(j, 1) = TextLine
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

This should put all the data into a single column.

From there you can parse the data using **Text-to-Columns** and process it as you choose.

Just be sure to replace the tildas before you save.

Comment: Right; to clarify I'm wanting people to open the file by double-clicking on it (with a `.csv` extension), so that makes running Macro code awkward. I'm wanting to see if it's possible for Excel's default open and save of csv files to not lose data